# When using 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS', why is the subquery's 'WHERE' clause necessary?

Tags: sql

Lets say we have two tables

Customers table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Henry |
| 3 | Sam |
| 4 | Max |

Orders table:

| id | customerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

I want to find the id of customers who never order. Basically, show me an output of all the Customers.id that do not appear in the Orders table which should be:

Expected output table:
| id |
|:---|
| 2|
| 4|

The SQL code to do this is:

```
SELECT Customers.id
FROM Customers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Orders.customerId
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Customers.id = Orders.customerId 
)
```

My question is: Why do we need to write the second WHERE clause? Wouldn't the subquery return the same result even without the WHERE clause?

How is:

```
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Orders.customerId
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Customers.id = Orders.customerId 
    )
```

different to:

```
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Orders.customerId
        FROM Orders
    )
```

However, the query returns zero rows without the 2nd WHERE clause and I don't understand why. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Second `WHERE` clause is to correlate the subquery to outer query.

Comment: The first outer where clause makes the query mean "show me all customers who have no orders". The second one means "show me all customers if the entire database has zero orders". The database obviously has at least one order and that's why the second query returns zero rows. The engine cannot read the developer's mind and assume a join where none is explicit.

Comment: @Igor On that link, I'm stuck on the part where it says "EXISTS valuate for TRUE/FALSE, and exits as TRUE on the first match of criteria".  What does "exits as TRUE" do? 

Does it mean that if the WHERE condition is satisfied it will "exit as TRUE" and OUTPUT the corresponding row? And if false, it just won't output the row?

Comment: If clause executed in the `EXISTS ()` returns at least 1 record it evaluates to `TRUE` for the tupple (record), otherwise `FALSE`. Without a WHERE clause there is no filtering for the tupple/record so at least 1 record will always be returned (assuming Orders has at least 1 record). Once you add the `WHERE` you are now joining the Customer record to the Order record and now the clause will return TRUE only if there is at least 1 record for the customer record being evaluated. `SELECT Orders.customerId` itself is not a filter but returns a cell/value in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to "join" the subquery to the main query

Imagine the inner query executed for each row of the main query.

If you don't use the inner `WHERE` clause the inner query (in your case) will always return rows, so the `NOT EXISTS` will always return `FALSE` for each customer.

Viceversa, if the Orders table is empty the inner query will not return rows so the `NOT EXISTS` will be `TRUE` for all the Customers.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the WHERE have to boolean, which means that they have to return TRUE or FALSE. If the subquery returns a number of lines is that true or false?
Your query could also be writen

```
SELECT Customers.id
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.id = Orders.customerId 
WHERE Orders.customerId IS NULL;
```

because the LEFT JOIN says take all records from the first table (Customers) whether we find a matching record in the second table. If there is no matching record all columns requested from the second table will be null.